# Regular Expression Matching for string "job XXXXXXX"

Tags: .net, regex

I can't seem to get this to work. I'm trying to match the text "job XXXXXXX" where the X is an integer.

Can't seem to crack it. I know its simply, but Regex is not my thing.

Here's what I'm working with. Any help would be appreciated.

```
^[job\s]([0-9]{7}$)
```

Shane

Comment: would it be possible to just strip out the 'job ' and use the remainder?

Answer (score 2):

```
^job\s+\d+$
```

^ match start of string

job - err..job

\s+ one or more spaces

\d+ one or more numbers

$ end of string

If you need the number, you can use

```
^job\s+(\d+)$
```

The parens around \d+ will put the number into a group that you can reference after the match.

**Edit**: Since you edited your original post, let me tell you why your edited regex isn't working:

```
^[job\s]([0-9]{7}$)
```

The [] in your regex creates a character set. Which means the regex is trying to match the letter j *or* the letter o *or* the letter b *or* a whitespace character, and THEN a number.

**Edit 2**:

To match a string like:

```
string x = @"Please refer to job 1000000 for more information";
```

You need a slightly different regex. You don't want to use ^ to match the beginning of the string or $ to match the end, because obviously that doesn't match the whole line.

Instead you'll want to do something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(x,@"job\s+(\d+)","REDACTED!!"));
```

If you want to refer to the number in your replace you can do something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(x, @"job\s+(\d+)", "Super Awesome Job: $1"));
```

Comment: +1 for giving the solution, explaining why it is right, and explaining why the original is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I'm beginning to understand this.

Comment: My next problem I'm not sure is a Regex issue. I'm using .NET RegEx.Replace(input, pattern, replace) and need to replace the right part in a string like "Please refer to job 1000000 for more information"

Comment: Yep I understand how that works. I've now got my text being replaced from "Job 1000000" to "Job $1". How can I reference the original 1000000 so that I can change $1 to a hyper link?

Comment: Regex.Replace(x, @"job\s+(\d+)", "<a href='ViewJob.aspx?id=$1'>Job</a>")

Comment: Of course! I don't know why I can't wrap my head around these this today! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression for it will be **^JOB\s\d{5}$** where 5 is count of digits in integer. incase count is not fixed then **^JOB\s\d+$**